# need advice two excel formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

#SOLVED -

=IF(AND(COUNTIF(b3:e3,"Yes")>=1,i3="Yes"),"Remove Online Module",IF(AND(COUNTIF(b3:e3,"No")=4,OR(i3={"Yes"})),"Complete Online Module",""))

I am looking for two formulas.
Hoping someone can help.

1. One for cell j3 to drag down.
   This formula would check the in house training completion in that row.
   If any training was complete and says yes in B3,C3,D3 or E3, they do not need to do training online. Therefore if outstanding online training says yes too, I want j3 to state
   "Remove online module".

If all training says no and outstanding online says yes, I want it to say complete online module.

If all say no for outstanding and completed, I want it to say No training logged"

2. The second formula I want is for k3 to drag down, I want it to list all people with no training at all logged.

This would be all outstanding and completed stating no and would return a name.

I have included in the image how I want it to provide a result.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Superuser,,,, for the issue simply use IF function,, like =if(B3="Yes", "Remove Training", "Carry Training") ☺

Comment: Hi Rajesh, thank you for your advice. IFOR FORMULA 1  - n this instance cell b3,d3,e3 and f3 are all training modules done on site. If any of them say yes and cell g3 says yes, I want it to state "Remove Online Module".  Otherwise it should state £Complete Online Module"

Comment: Count the occurences of "yes" in the range: `IF(COUNTIF(B3:F3, "yes")>0, "Remove Training", "Carry Training")`

Comment: The left hand training is in house. The right is online.

Comment: It needed to factor in both. I have included the formula that works I was given. Thank you for your help